# iPad Simulator Runs Old Version of My App

Tags: xcode, ipad, simulator

So, in my first run-through creating my app, I hastily created a terrible file structure that annoyed me, so I decided to create a new version of the same app, and start from scratch using some of the same old stuff in new files. When I build the new app in the iPad simulator, the simulator runs the old app even though I have deleted all references to the old project file and folder.

Not sure what I can do to make it run the new version of my app instead of the old one. Any suggestions?

iPad simulator runs an old version of an app that I recreated instead of the new version on build

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the old App in simulator / Reset Contents & Settings via the Simulator menu.

Answer (score 0):

You should not only remove your old app from simulator, but also if you are building a new one on an old project file/workspace, open Xcode's Organizer -> Projects, find your project and delete it, make Clean on your project, then close Xcode and reopen it. That'll make sure you get clean and complete rebuild.

Comment: Thanks for the help...I was forgetting the restart Xcode part. Thanks though!